# I can't know how this line convert from java to kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i canont know how this line convert from java to kotlin the code of nearby places for android

```
Task<Location> task=fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
```

i make application to get nearby places convert code java to kotlin but this line cannot convert it

Comment: What is the **specific** problem?

Comment: i need convert this line code form java to kotlin

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Task<Location>()=fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
this line give me Cannot create an instance of an abstract class ,Variable expected

Comment: Have you read the basic syntax documentation for Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this line to Kotlin just like this. Before you call make sure the location permission.

```
val task: Task<Location> = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
```

Comment: thank you so much code run good

Comment: Please learn the basic Kotlin first.